# How to filter by BooleanField in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have been having a hard time accomplishing this task and it seems that I cannot get help anywhere I turn. I am trying to send `Memo`s to specific user `group`s in Django. Each user in each `group` should receive the `Memo` and be able to change the `BooleanField` to `True` to signify that they have read it.

I then need to be able to access the amount of users which received and have marked the `BoolenField` as `True` so I can create a table in a template which says [3/31 Read] and such.

I would like to not use `GenericForeignkey`s if possible and I would like to keep it as one Model if possible but I know that may not work. Currently I was trying this:

```
class Memo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('memos-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I was going to access each user (receiver) within the group which is selected on the `MemoCreateForm` then apply that user to this model:

```
class ReceivedMemo(models.Model):
    memo = models.ForeignKey(
        Memo, related_name='user_memos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='memos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then I was going to try to filter the `ReceivedMemos` by `memo` to see if each `receiver` has `read` the memo or not. But this is starting to get complicated and I am not sure if it will work. Am I going about this the right way? Or should I be able to have one Model such as:

```
class Memo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Seems that each object would have the `BooleanField` applied to the object and not the user though.

Comment: I think your intuition about two models is correct, but with a slight tweak that I am not 100% sure how to implement: create your "ReceivedMemo" (or "ReadReceipt" maybe?) model to track individual receipt/reads by recipients. But in your "Mark Receipt Read" processing keep track of the total counts for display. When you send the memo, record the number of recipients in the "Memo" model, and increment a "ReadCount" field on the "Memo" model itself. Then when you are displaying your "3 of 31 read" the DB lookup for the view will be fast and easy! Does this make sense?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe this would be better `django annotations`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7206705/3911355

Comment: So I know that I can just filter for all, or read, then the length of the query set to get the count. My question should be, are my models set up the correct way? And if so, do I just access the `Memo` model group, in the view, that the user selected to apply the data to the new `ReceivedMemo` object? Or I guess - how do I put the `Memo` object data in the `ReceivedMemo` object? Do I just access the `Memo` objects receiver (group) in the view and then create a new object with the `ReceivedMemo` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReceivedMemo` model seems more appropriate rather than the `read` bit, but the issue with this approach is that whenever you create a new `Memo` you need to also create lots of (for every `User` in the `Group`) `ReceivedMemo` objects with `read=False`? This seems pointless. Maybe you can just store the Users which actually read this thing, and for everyone that's left, consider he has not read it. I.e.

```
class Memo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    read_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am new to Django so it is all a little confusing. So how would I store the user that read a memo? I understand the models more than anything else. Would I need a signal that adds the user like `Memo.read_by.add('user')` whenever the memo is read?

Comment: You just add the relation as explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), e.g. `memo.read_by.add(request.user)`, you can get how many users read it with `memo.read_by.count()` and the total `count` of all users you get from the `memo.receiver` attribute, `User.objects.filter(group__in=memo.reveiver.all()).count()`. About the signal, well its up to you to decide when a user actually read the memo and a relation needs to be added.

Comment: I got ya. Thanks!